# Focus of parabola using only a ruler

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-constructions

It is an easy exercise that using ruler and compass one find the focus of a given parabola.

Can one do the same using only a ruler? -- if not, why?

Comment: Is this for a _ruler_ or a straightedge and compass?

Comment: @Random832: yes, perhaps, but i don't know -- my native languages are Russian, Maths and "things-as-they-are". But if you talk about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_edge then i agree!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, because there exists a projective map which preserves the parabola but does not preserve its focus (this is so for any conic and any point.)

Comment: Fantastic! It's very easy and hence beautiful and hence genius! Happy New Year

Comment: How do you prove this?

Comment: You need to define the focus and by doing so I guess you might already see that this is not projective. Also there are points that are always preserved by a projective transform, the point at infinity in the case of the parabola so this contradicts your final statement. Can you modify it to make it always hold?

Comment: Assume that there is some construction on the plane $\pi$ which given parabola $\gamma$ gives its focus $F$. Let $T$ be projective map for which $T(\gamma)$ is a parabola again, but $T(F)$ is not it's focus. Apply the same construction to $T(\gamma)$ on $T(\pi)$, we get $T(F)$. Contradiction.